# Hard redirect file.php to /file (when /file is already being transparently redirected to /file.php)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Am already transparently redirecting requests for `/file` to `/file.php` -- accessing `/file` shows `/file.php`. My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Would now like to do a *hard redirect* for `/file.php` to `/file` -- if I hit up `/file.php`, URL in the address bar must show `/file`. Tried the following but didn't work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)\.php$ $1 [R]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform your rewrite based on the request that the user sent to the server. Something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s/([a-zA-Z]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```